# Creating Menu's Qt

Tags: qt, menubar

Looking at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/mainwindows-menus.html they have a call to menuBar(), what is this and where does it come from? When I try to use the code below in Qt I get "->must point to class/struct/union/generic type" error

```
file = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("File"));
```

Comment: QMainWindow. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html

Answer (score 3):

In the example,  `MainWindow` is a subclass of `QMainWindow` (see the declaration near the top)

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
```

Therefore the line

```
fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File"));
```

within the method

```
void MainWindow::createMenus()
```

is a reference to the `menuBar()` method of the base class `QMainWindow`.